# Do released objects take the direction and speed of their parent frame's velocity, or just the parent frame's speed component?

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, velocity, relative-motion

Context: I'm working on a space game. I noticed that an unpowered object fired from a strafing spaceship appeared, as the released object moved, to curve in the direction the ship was strafing. This looked wrong, and seems wrong compared against simulated physical reality.

The original code used the firing spaceship's velocity -- its speed and direction of movement -- as the starting value for the fired object's velocity. I modified this code to use only the speed component of the firing spaceship's velocity.

With this new code, fired objects appear to move as intended: in a straight line once fired, with the parent's starting speed plus their own inherent speed. This conforms to my belief that, in classical mechanics, ignoring gravity and wind resistance, an object released from a parent frame starts moving with only its parent frame's speed -- not its parent frame's velocity, including the parent frame's direction component.

However, others on the project (who are sharp people I respect) are insisting I'm wrong, and that a released object does start moving with its parent frame's velocity, including the parent frame's direction component.

Who's right? And why?

---

Here's an example to illustrate my belief that an independently released unpowered object, at the moment it's released, receives only the speed component of its parent frame, not its parent's direction component of velocity. (Again, this excludes gravity, wind resistance, etc.)

If independent objects, when released, begin moving with their parent frame's direction, then a bullet fired from a train moving past a stationary target outside the train would, when fired, keep moving in the direction that the train is moving plus its own direction of movement. It would *curve* in motion because it would begin movement with both its own velocity when released and its parent frame's velocity, including the parent frame's direction component.

But that does not appear to be what actually happens. Instead, a fired bullet -- an independent object -- moves in a straight line along its own direction component of its velocity, independent of the parent frame's direction, as soon as it's fired. In this example, a fired bullet has the starting speed of the train in the direction the train is moving, but that speed is not applied to the bullet in the train's direction -- it's applied only as the starting speed of the bullet along the bullet's own independent direction... and thus the bullet (more generally, any independent object) travels in a straight line as soon as it's fired.

Helpful thoughts and comments on this are welcome!

Comment: If I fire a bullet from a train it indeed does inherit a component of velocity due to the motion of the train and that which was imparted by the combustion so that it's total velocity in a ground frame is at an angle to the direction of the train. There isn't any curvature involved here and Im not sure why you think the resulting path will be curved.

Comment: Your friends are right.  I suspect either some perceptual effect (you're viewing it at an angle, or there's some sort of distortion in the rendering), or an outright bug in the game's physics engine code (i.e., it's _supposed_ to be taking initial velocity from the parent craft, but it's somehow continuing to inherit a changing velocity as the parent craft accelerates).

Comment: How can you ignore the parent's direction but apply its speed -- do you apply it in a random direction? And how do you arrive at a curved path for an unaccelerated object? You add, after all, two constants.

Comment: when you shoot a bullet from a train at a 90-degree right-angle, does it go farther when the train is going faster? shouldn't it go very very far since the earth is moving quite fast around the sun? for that matter, when you throw a ball at your friend, wouldn't it go straight through his head and kill him because of the earth speed being applied in the direction of your friend?

Comment: I have a suspicion that you might be basing your intuition on vertically scrolling shoot em ups, which do typically have this (unphysical) projectile behaviour. At least they don't carry horizontal velocity to the projectile, vertical velocity is less obvious to see whether it's carried or not

Comment: all you have to do is look at video of astronauts on the ISS to see released objects stay consistent with the parent (the ISS).

Comment: For the bullet fired from a train, part of your issue is that the component of velocity imparted by the gun is so large that it may make the train's velocity negligibly small in comparison. However, if the gun has a low muzzle velocity, the train's movement means that the gunner must adjust aim to lead the target as though the (actually stationary) target is moving with the opposite of the train's velocity. If the gunner on the train aims directly at a stationary target, the bullet will miss, traveling in a straight line slightly to one side of the target.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I am understanding your question, your colleagues are correct.  When an object is given velocity $\overrightarrow{\textbf{v}}_0$ inside a frame moving with velocity $\overrightarrow{\textbf{v}}_m$ a stationary observer outside of that frame would see that object as moving with velocity $\overrightarrow{\textbf{v}}_s=\overrightarrow{\textbf{v}}_0+\overrightarrow{\textbf{v}}_m$.

Your statement that objects should just gain the speed but not the direction can be argued against as follows.  Imagine you are moving in space with some velocity and you release an object but give it no velocity within your frame.  Then in your frame you would just continue to see that object move along side you and go nowhere.  Thus, to someone else who is not in your frame and sees you as moving, would see the object continue to move along side you at whatever your velocity was before releasing it.  If it just gained the speed you would be forced to eventually ask the question "which direction should I see it go?".

In your train example nothing would curve if we are ignoring all acceleration.  According to the person outside the train the bullet would move in the direction obtained from the previously mentioned vector addition and this would be a straight line.  The angle of travel with respect to the ground would differ between the two frames but this is normal.  Imagine a simpler example where a ball is dropped on the train.  On the train the people see the ball go straight down while outside the train an observer would see the ball follow a parabolic trajectory (it's curved because gravity causes the ball to accelerate rather than just gain a velocity).  This can be viewed explicitly [here](https://youtu.be/ODwnl6H6t54?t=122).  With no acceleration and just a constant downward velocity in the train, the path would be a straight line going down and to the left/right depending on the direction the train is going.

A pedantic note:  all of this discussion assumes the frames are non-relativistic i.e. moving much slower than the speed of light.  If this were not true things would get more complicated and we would have to involve [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation).

Answer (score 18):

> This conforms to my belief that, in classical mechanics, ignoring gravity and wind resistance, an object released from a parent frame starts moving with only its parent frame's speed -- not its parent frame's velocity, including the parent frame's direction component.

This is incorrect. If an object is simply released from a “parent” object (without applying any force) then it will have the same velocity, both speed and direction, as the parent.

However, the more usual case would be for the object to be launched rather than just released. In that case, the **initial** velocity would be equal to the vector sum of the parent’s velocity and the launching velocity relative to the parent.

> the released object moved, to curve

A curved path indicates acceleration. This would be appropriate only for objects with their own propulsion, like a rocket or a torpedo. For a projectile without propulsion the path should be straight. If you are seeing a curve then that indicates a different error than incorrectly setting the initial velocity.

The initial velocity should be the parent’s velocity plus the launch velocity relative to the parent. Then any acceleration, including curving, must be the result of some explicit force acting on it.

Comment: I wish I could mark more than one response as an Answer, because this is also excellent. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, that is very kind

Answer (score 1):

A *gedankenexperiment* should make clear that you must apply both the parent's  speed and direction to a released object:

Imagine the object to be released is still attached to the parent; they form **one object.** The object is in free-fall, which makes it an inertial system. Now you make the connection gradually thinner until it ceases to exist. There is nothing magical happening at the moment of separation, when the last connecting atom is disappearing: The now-released object is still traveling with the parent, as before. It must have inherited both the parent's speed *and* the direction.

Any change to that — any *acceleration* — needs a force. Because the acceleration would happen relative to the parent, the resulting velocity is *superimposed* on the parent's: The two vectors are added for an outside observer.

Answer (score 0):

You are in error.

The easiest way to see this is to have someone stand in a train moving at a constant speed.  Then have them toss a ball up into the air, then have it fall back down and catch it.

Inside the train, tossing the ball into the air and catching it is strait up and down.

From outside the train, the ball's velocity is the sum of the up-throwing action and the train's velocity.  Anything else would be insane.

Your bullet analogy doesn't give you this intuition, because bullets are insanely fast compared to almost anything else you are used to thinking about.  A bullet can approach 3000 km/h; even a car going at highway speeds is moving slow relative to it.

If you shoot out the side of a highway speed car at something 10m away, the bullet takes almost 0.1 seconds to hit the target, moving the point of impact by a bit less than 30 centimeters (or under a foot) from where the gun was aimed.

You can reframe things by looking at things from the perspective of the shooter; they are stationary from their perspective, and the target is moving at 100 km/h backwards.  Just like you'd have to lead when aiming at any other moving target, the shooter has to aim almost 30 cm "ahead" (really behind) of the target 10 m away.

Answer (score 0):

> However, others on the project (who are sharp people I respect) are insisting I'm wrong, and that a released object does start moving with its parent frame's velocity, including the parent frame's direction component.

That is incorrect. Either you are incorrectly presenting your colleagues' position, or you are *both* wrong. A released object does not "start" moving with its patent frame's velocity. It is *already* moving with its parent frame's velocity. A bullet is not a good example, because its total velocity is such a high multiple of the train's velocity that the latter doesn't have a significant effect. There's also the issue of gravity, so let's imagine there's a train traveling at North 10 m/s right next to some frictionless ice.

Now imagine you throw a ball to the East with a speed of 10 m/s relative to the train. Before you started throwing the ball, it had a speed of 10 m/s N. As you throw it, it gain velocity in the Eastern direction. By the time you release it, it has a velocity of 10 m/s N and 10 m/s E, for a total of 14 m/s NE (since the two velocities are at right angles, the total velocity follows the Pythagorean Theorem:  $v_{\text total}^2=v_1^2+v_2^2$). It *always* had the 10 m/s N, and from the moment you release it, its total velocity is 14 m/s. It doesn't start with the 10 m/s E, and then "curve" towards the NE direction.

What happens if you throw the ball so that's going 10 m/s S, relative to the train? If we add those two velocities, then we get that it's stationary, relative to the ground. But using your rule, it would go 20 m/s S. How does throwing it from a train going North make its Southerly velocity *more* than if you threw it while standing still?

Moreover, your rule violates relativity. You're saying the ball starts out with a speed of 10 m/s, and then that gets added to the speed it's thrown at. But according to someone on the train, the ball starts with a velocity of zero, so its final speed should be equal to the speed at which it is thrown.

Your hypothesis get weirder as the speed at which you throw the ball gets smaller and smaller. Suppose you throw the ball at just 1 m/s. Now if you throw the ball to the North, it should go at 11 m/s N, but if you throw it South, it should go 11 m/s S. If you throw it at 0.01 m/s, then throwing it North will make it go 10.01 m/s N, and throwing it South will make it go 10.01 m/s S. How does the direction of such as small tap make such a big difference? You could slightly nudge the ball, and it would suddenly go flying off the back of the train. If you were in an airplane traveling at the speed of sound North, then tossing a penny to someone in the back of the plane would result in the penny suddenly rocketing towards them at the speed of sound South.